# how to export a subsite as wsp with master and page layouts?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

When i try to export the subsite the wsp file does not include the required page layouts and master. Can somebody point me in the right direction how i can ensure those files will be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

out of the box, Master pages are downloaded separately via the master page gallery.

All SharePoint farms of the same version have the same available layouts pages, unless those layouts pages were added custom.  In that case, whatever custom code / solutions were used should be used to reinstall the custom layouts pages into the new location.  There are more ways around this, but this is how you should start.

Comment: Well the layouts have been created by myself using Sharepoint Designer. So how can i get a solution from those?

Comment: So long as there is no code behind, you should be able to simply copy paste these.  You could even copy it in spd, paste it to your file system, and move it to the new server/farm.  Not the prettiest way to do it, but I believe this should work.  

I'd also suggest looking into the different backup methods SharePoint offers, there's literally 10s of them, and usually you can find at least one that fits whichever scenario you face.  gl!